# BLE relay to control my garage door - security concerns

Tags: relay, bluetooth-low-energy, security

I would like to use Shelly 1PM Mini Gen3 to control my garage door. Since I do not have WiFi coverage in my garage I will rely on Bluetooth. However with this setup I am not sure if this Smart home bluetooth relay has secure enough system to be used for things like garage door. Do you have any recommendation?